# three.js animated texture in particles with custom shadermaterial

Tags: three.js

How do I make each particle animate and cycle through all the tiles in the sprite sheet?

Here's my shader program:

```
<script type="x-shader/x-vertex" id="vertexshader"> 

attribute vec2 offset; 
varying vec2 vOffset; 

void main() 
{ 
     vOffset = offset; 
     gl_PointSize = 25.0; 
     gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 ); 
} 
</script> 

<script type="x-shader/x-fragment" id="fragmentshader"> 

uniform sampler2D texture; 
uniform vec2 repeat; 
varying vec2 vOffset; 

void main() 
{ 
     vec2 uv = vec2( gl_PointCoord.x, 1.0 - gl_PointCoord.y ); 
     vec4 tex = texture2D( texture, uv * repeat + vOffset ); 
     if ( tex.a < 0.5 ) discard; 

     gl_FragColor = tex; 
} 
</script>
```

Basically an example from here: http://jsfiddle.net/myy7x4zd/4/